# Segmentation fault in C when using fgets and fscanf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets, scanf

i'm trying to read the first line of a text file and then skip over it using fgets but it's giving me a seg fault, can someone help me? It worked before I added the fgets, therefore it seems that the fgets is the problem.

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int N
    const int STACK_SIZE=65536;
    int col=0;
    int i;
    int j;
    FILE *file1;
    int s;
    int row=0;
    int prev='t';
    char m[1024];

    if(argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <Executable> <Input file> <Threads>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    file1=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(file1==NULL) //check to see if file exists
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    stack=malloc(STACK_SIZE);
    if(stack==NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(atoi(argv[2]) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Threads has to be a number.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fscanf(file1,"%d",&N);
    rewind(file1);

    fgets(m,sizeof(m),file1);
    while((s=fgetc(file1)) != EOF)
    {
        if(s == ' ')
        {
            prev='a';
            continue;
        }
        if(s == '\n' && prev != '\n')
        {
            row++;
            if(col != N)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "File %s has incorrect columns.\n", argv[1]);
                exit(1);
            }
            col=0;
            prev='a';
        }
        if(s != ' ' && s != '\n')
        {
            col++;
            prev='a';
        }
    }
    if(row != N)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"File %s has incorrect rows.\n", argv[1]);
        exit(0);
    }
    rewind(file1);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            fscanf(file1,"%d",&A[i][j]);
        }
    }

    fclose(file1);
}
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
Fixed. Code placement was the only problem.

Comment: Your *real* code checks that `file1` for NULL to validate the file opened prior to sending it to either `fscanf` or `fgets` , *right* ?? "Assumption is the mother of all...."

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, i checked it in my real code

Comment: Then post your "real" code, including the `#include` list and a compilable `main()` and comment-mark the precise line where the seg-fault is being reported in your debugger. Also validate `arg[1]` is in fact an actual null-term string pointer and that `argc` is at least **2**.

Comment: @AndrewChan do not post some code that you think is problematic, when the problem is in your real code, now I gave you two wrong answers. And the new code has something also suspicious, you need to post a reproducible sample of the real probelm.

Comment: what if `argc < 3`? also `exit(1)` every time an error occurs is not good, you need to cleanup before.

Comment: @iharob it's to check if there are less than 3 command line arguments, **there must be exactly 3 arguments**

Comment: Yes but you have `if (argc != 3)`  it will be false if `argc < 3`.

Comment: Why did you add `fgets()`?

Comment: The posted code won't even compile now.  missing semi-colon after `int N`, `stack` is undeclared, `A` is undeclared. Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) *please*.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ok, lets just ignore some of the minor details and assume that it doesn't have syntax errors and that the undeclared variables are declared.

Comment: Ok so throwing out all the *minor* details would be reducing what you posted to what @iharob has in his answer. And you're saying *that* fails with a seg-fault as well? I'm genuinely curious: what is the real *type* of `stack` and where is it *really* used ? (more interested in the former than the latter).

Comment: @WhozCraig Ok, you can ignore stack for now because i'm using that for the clone(2) function, clone(fn,childstack etc etc). Stack is a char *stack. And yes it still does fail.

Comment: @AndrewChan I understand, then it should be stripped from your post. I didn't ask if it *failed*. I asked if it *seg-faulted*. That answer code is designed to fail *gracefully* via error detection. If that **exact** code *as he wrote it* still seg-faults, then you have runtime-issues beyond your code (and his).

Comment: Don't keep us in suspense. *What was the problem?*. Post an answer if you wish. (you can answer your own questions, and SO encourages it).

Comment: @WhozCraig ha, it's not even worth saying. Just code placement errors.

Comment: Welcome to the club. that only happens every few days for most of our careers =P Good you found it. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

You don't check that the file opened, `fscanf()` and `fgets()` expect a valid `FILE *` you need to check [`fopen()`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?fopen+3)'s return value<sup>1</sup>, you should also ensure that an argument was provided in the command line, for that you can check `argc` in the following code an example

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char  buffer[1024];
    FILE *file;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "you need to provide a file name.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL) /* problem opening */
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error openning %s\n", filename);
        return 2;
    }
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL)
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    fclose(file); /* close the file */
    return 0;
}
```

the code above will not fail, even if the program was invoked with the wrong number of arguments or the program fails to open the file, or if it fails to read from it.

---

<sub>1. `fopen()` returns `NULL` when it fails to open the file.</sub>

Comment: Sorry, I editted the post. It was in my code but i forgot to include it in here